# Updating web code causes Designer.cs file to replace WebControls.ListItem with HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, designer

I have a legacy web project created in visual studio 2005 that has been recently upgraded to visual studio 2010.  It builds against .net 2.0

It contains an ascx user control that contains a fragment that looks like

```
<select runat="server" id="foo">
    <option runat="server" id="bar" value="1">1</option>
</select>
```

The original designer code looks like this:

```
protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem bar;
```

Whenever I edit anything in the .ascx file (even adding a line break), the designer automatically updates to look like this:

```
protected global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl bar;
```

At that point, the page stops working and provides me the following runtime error:

> Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: The base class includes the field 'bar', but its type (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl) is not compatible with the type of control (System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem).

I then have to hand edit the ascx.designer.cs file to fix the damage that visual studio did.

What can I do to stop visual studio from eating my designer file, short of rewriting all of the legacy option select fragments into asp listcontrol objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. I changed some part of my ASP.net project and after that I reached this problem :

```
The base class includes the field 'Option1', 
but its type (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl) is not compatible 
with the type of control (System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem).
```

For fixing this problem, I modified this file `<MyFileName>.aspx.designer.cs` and I searched `Option1` and I have replaced

```
protected global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl.ListItem Option1;
```

with

```
protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem Option1;
```

Finally, I built my solution and my problem have gone.

Comment: Yes, until you make a change to the ascx again, then the problem is back.

Comment: In my case, I has been fixed and I have never have the same problem.

Comment: Marking as solved.  If I recall correctly, this was the way to temporarily solve the issue, but with every edit it came back.  We ended up rewriting the application in angular, so this became a non-issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is incorrect.

`<option>` is a child of `<select>`, but you've got `<select>` as a child of `<option>`, which is wrong.

It should be:

```
<select runat="server" id="foo">
    <option runat="server" id="bar" value="1">1</option>
</select>
```

Note that the `title=""` attribute has no effect on `<option>` elements.

Comment: Sorry, My paraphrasing in the original question was incorrect.  The html is actually in the nesting order that you specified.  I updated the question with the correct html code.